# Setting up XML file - use attr or elements for multiple values

Tags: xml, jquery

I am setting up an XML file for a web site that I am creating. The XML file is to contain art (image) details. Each art record can have multiple sizes available (size1, size2, etc.) for purchase and multiple categories (cat1, cat2, cat3, etc). What is the best way to setup the xml file for multiple values? Here are the two options that I can think of.

---

...With elements for size and category...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<images>
    <image id='' ImageName=''>
        <title></title>

        <sizes>
            <size>size1</size>
            <size>size2</size>
        </sizes>

        <categories>
            <category>cat1</category>
            <category>cat2</category>
        </categories>

        <description>
            <short></short>
            <long></long>
        </description>
    </image>
</images>
```

with JQuery ajax, I reference each size / category with the following...

```
$(xml).find('image').each(function(){
    $(this).find('size').each(function(){
        var size = $(this).text();
        {do something here with the size variable}
    });
});
```

---

...OR...

---

...With attributes for size and category...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<images>
    <image id='' ImageName='' sizes='size1 size2' category='cat1 cat2 cat3'>
        <title></title>

        <description>
            <short></short>
            <long></long>
        </description>
    </image>
</images>
```

with JQuery ajax, I can reference each size / category with the following...

```
$(xml).find('image').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('size').split(' ');
        {Loop through each split attribute}
});
```

---

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you have another option with the Elements... `<Size sizeName='size1' />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take advantage of the intrinsic nature of xml to define and document the relationships in the data it marks up.

Use of elements for multiple values conceptually keeps the xml representation of your object closer to the model without requiring you have an understanding of the domain to interpret it.

```
<Image>
    <Sizes>
        <Size sizeName="size1"/>
        <Size sizeName="size2"/>
    </Sizes>
</Image>
```

It is clear here that there are two sizes.

A space inside a string has no intrinsic meaning in xml

```
<Image sizes="size1 size2" />
```

This may be clear there are two size, but only because of your understanding of sizes.

```
<Blarg bebos="sldkd eldks" />
```

Is this one bebos value of `sldkd eldks` or two bebo values of `sldkd` and `eldks`?
But...

```
<Blarg>
    <Bepos>
        <Bepo value="sldkd"/>
        <Bepo value="eldks"/>
    </Bepos>
</Blarg>
```

You would not want to return to a project a year later, or pick up somebody elses code, with the intention of adding or changing functionality and not realize you had to go through extra steps to make the pure data behave properly.

Comment: Wow. Great detailed response. Thanks.

Is...
    <Bepo value="sldkd"/>

equivalent to
    <Bepo>sldkd</Bepo>?

Comment: In your exmaple, was the use of sizeName as an attribute intentional or should this be value too?

Comment: With <Bepo value="sldkd"/>, "sldkd" is the value of an attribute. With <Bepo>sldkd</Bepo>, "sldkd" is a text node inside the element (not the same thing).

Comment: @JoeFletch value and sizeName are just names of attributes, unless you are working with a defined xml schema you can name your attributes and elements whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

There's no single "correct" approach, but using elements is more flexible of course, because you can add child elements later should the need arise. In my opinion, the XPath expressions will also tend be more simple for elements than for attributes when you want to check whether a given value is present, etc.

I would also think about whether the categories are likely to repeat. If so, consider modelling the categories separately and referring to them by id. That way, for example, renaming a category can be done by changing the single definition.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am not familiar with XPath Expressions. Can you give me an example of what you are talking about? In the meantime I will look up XPath Expressions.

I also agree with your comment about Category / Size IDs. This is similar to how I have setup databases in the past. Do you have any links to setting up something like this with XML?

Comment: If you're a beginner, www.w3schools.com is an ok place to start. The official specs for XPath etc. are at www.w3c.org, but reading those can be pretty hard-core. An example of XPath would be, using your exampe, "/Images/Image" to select all images, or "/Images/Image[1]/Description/Short" to select the short description of the first image (actually all descriptions, but presumably there would be just one). Attributes are referred to using "@", for example "Images/Image/@id". The database analogy is a good one; it's the same kind of relational modelling I had in mind.

Comment: To add to the flexibility, using Elements allows any naming you want per size/category as opposed having to arbitrarily choosing some delimiter. `<Size>large rectangle</Size>`

Comment: @Dabbler And I can use XPath with JQuery's $.ajax() function to get the data from the XML file? Or is there a different technology to use to get the XML data.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor Good call. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multi-valued properties of an object that you want to model in XML, using child elements is cleaner, easier to process/search, more extensible. But using space-separated attributes (a simple example of a micro-syntax - that is a syntax which is understood by your application but not by the XML parser) may be more economical/efficient. So, use the space-separated attribute approach only if you can prove to your satisfaction that the machine savings (e.g. in space and transmission time) are really necessary and justify the extra programmer effort.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Makes total sense...now! Is the $.each() code the correct method of accessing these multiple elements?